# onmouseover and canvas, not continuous

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, onmouseover

I'd like to display continuously updating coordinates when the mouse is over a canvas.

The below *Firefox-tested* code should produce this, but onmouseover is only called when the mouse enters the canvas. When over it, nothing happens and the coordinates are not updated.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<Canvas width="200" height="200" onmouseover="myMouse(event)">No support</Canvas>
<P id="text"/>

<Script>
function myMouse(event) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Position = " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY;
}
</Script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What can I do to have onmouseover be continuous, and not only update when the mouse enters the canvas?

On the web, the closest subject I've found was [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/128474/onmouseover-not-continous.html), but they did not answer the question on making this work ... I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `onmouseover` try `onmousemove`.

The onmouseover event fires when the mouse moves over an element once. The onmousemove event fires whenever the mouse is being moved.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zsNkj/)**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onmousemove

Comment: Even then you won't get truly continuous feedback. You can easily see this by just drawing into the canvas on each `onmousemove` call. If you move the mouse at a pretty typical rate, you end up with a spotty dotted line.

Comment: @MattGreer - Seems smooth to me. Bottom line is mouseover fires once when you hit the element while mousemove is continuous.